# Force close in the arrays

Tags: android, arrays

This is a bit of code from a section of my app where I am trying to allow people to view the sections that they favorites. I have it working for that part. Now I'm trying to make it so that when onLongClick it allows the option to delete one. I do not know whether that part works yet because I am currently experiencing an error in the array section from what I have narrowed it down to. Its very weird because from what I can see the difference from it working and not there really shouldn't be any problem. Maybe I need some fresh eyes looking at this if you will. Thanks

```
public class Favorites extends ListActivity{

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "Favorites";
    String[] title;
    int favNum, num;
    int[] category, member;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      grabFav();
      num = favNum;
      num++;
      if(favNum > -1){
          title = new String[num];
          category = new int[num];
          member = new int[num];
          allFavs();

          setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item_list, title));

          ListView lv = getListView();
          lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);      
      }
    }

    public void grabFav(){
         SharedPreferences saved = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
         favNum = saved.getInt("FavoriteNum", -1);
    }

    public void allFavs(){
        SharedPreferences saved = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

        for(int i = 0; i< favNum; i++){
            title[i] = saved.getString("Title"+i, "");
        }

        for(int n = 0; n< favNum; n++){
            category[n] = saved.getInt("Category"+n, 0);
        }

        for(int m = 0; m< favNum; m++){
            member[m] = saved.getInt("Member"+m, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

When that top part looks like this

```
grabFav();
  favNum++;

  if(favNum > 0){
      title = new String[favNum];
      category = new int[favNum];
      member = new int[favNum];
      allFavs();
```

It works fine (not sure about the onLongItemClick because I normally have it commented out so I can find the error). From what I can tell it should be working just fine. I posted the whole class incase you notice another error in it that will likely cause problems. Here is the log cat if you want to look

```
09-04 11:09:20.576: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18769): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-04 11:09:20.576: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18769): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-04 11:09:20.576: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18769):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:355)
09-04 11:09:20.576: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18769):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
09-04 11:09:20.576: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18769):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
09-04 11:09:20.576: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18769):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1727)
09-04 11:09:20.576: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18769):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:652)
09-04 11:09:20.576: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18769):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:709)
09-04 11:09:20.576: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18769):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1580)
09-04 11:09:20.576: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18769):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1147)
09-04 11:09:20.576: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18769):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
09-04 11:09:20.576: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18769):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
09-04 11:09:20.576: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18769):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
09-04 11:09:20.576: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18769):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
09-04 11:09:20.576: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18769):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
09-04 11:09:20.576: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18769):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
09-04 11:09:20.576: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18769):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
09-04 11:09:20.576: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18769):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
09-04 11:09:20.576: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18769):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
09-04 11:09:20.576: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18769):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1045)
09-04 11:09:20.576: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18769):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
09-04 11:09:20.576: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18769):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-04 11:09:20.576: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18769):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-04 11:09:20.576: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18769):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-04 11:09:20.576: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18769):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-04 11:09:20.576: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18769):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-04 11:09:20.576: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18769):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
09-04 11:09:20.576: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18769):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
09-04 11:09:20.576: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18769):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You need to reduce the amount of code, this will both help you find the problem and encourage more answers on SO.

Comment: @Philipp Ok I reduced the size some. I left the stuff that it is calling though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked, that all the title strings you get from your preferences actually exist, i.e. that this line does not assign `null` to `title[i]`:

```
title[i] = saved.getString("Title"+i, "");
```

Maybe you're missing the zeroth title "Title0" and start only at "Title1"?

Comment: Nah that was an issue I fixed earlier. The list view favorite would populate after the next favorite was favorited. That was cause when favNum is first called it is -1 until it is incremented after each favorite. So it does start at 0 as the for loop does. It may have something to do with in that area so I'll try some stuff with it. Thanks.

Comment: You were on to something. I basically just switched the roles of num and favNum in a few places and it fixed that problem. By the way do you happen to know of a way to update the list view after I accept deleting one?

Comment: If you store your `ArrayAdapter` in an instance field of your `Activity`, you can then use [ArrayAdapter.remove()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#remove(T)) on it in `onContextItemSelected()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this format where you immediately set the content of your activity before using views. I used to get NullPointer exceptions whenever I called methods on views before 
the setContentView method.. Hope this'll resolve your problem :)

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_xml); 

// your code

}
```

'

Comment: I tried it and it was a good idea, but the problem is still persistent in the array some how. Reason I didn't have the setContent view was because of Googles ListView code does it without. Thanks